# Custom field size in Plone 4 using Dexterity

Tags: forms, field, plone, dexterity

A quickie: **how does one specify a custom field size (width and height) in a schemata using Dexterity?**

For example, a textarea (schema.Text) width is set to 100%. I'd like to specify a default width and height, to make it more useful.

How does one achieve this? I tried looking into *plone.directives.form*, but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 100% width is actually coming from public.css, and not anything in Dexterity or z3c.form. If you want to override it, you could do so with your stylesheet, or if it is specific to that particular field, you could specify the "style" attribute in your field schema to supply field-specific inline CSS.

Comment: Overall I think this is the simplest (almost too obvious) solution. I'll register a custom stylesheet for my product.